# Ловить все события клика кроме кликов в определенных блоках

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div id="block_1">.. тут множество вложенных блоков ..</div>
<div id="block_2">.. тут множество вложенных блоков ..</div>
<div id="block_3">.. тут множество вложенных блоков ..</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы появлялся *alert* только когда были клики в блоке **block_3**, в том числе и на любой вложенный его элемент(блок).

Сейчас у меня просто ловит любой клик в любом месте.

```
$("*").click(function (eclick) {
    alert('нужный мне клик');
});
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем проблема сделать так?

```js
$("#block_3").click(function (eclick) {
    alert('нужный мне клик');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block_1">.. тут множество вложенных блоков ..</div>
<div id="block_2">.. тут множество вложенных блоков ..</div>
<div id="block_3">
cxvc
  <div>001</div>
  <div>002</div>
  <div>003</div>
  <div>004</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: почему-то у меня не срабатывает. я просто встраиваю этот код в чужой сайт (расширение хром).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#block_3").click(function (e) {
  alert('нужный мне клик');
});
```